# Utilizing PySpark, determin how many of the elements within an array column are contained within an array of arrays in another column

Tags: arrays, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have a data set like below:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+
|                col1|                col2|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|[[563], [242, 178]] |          [563, 178]|
|[[563], [242, 178]] |     [563, 178, 242]|
|[[563], [242, 178]] |     [563, 242, 178]|
|[[563], [242, 178]] |     [242, 178, 563]|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

What I would like to be able to do is identify how many values *in order* from **col2** are contained within **col1**.
Order in **col1** matters only at the top level array, and does not matter at the lower level array.

For instance the output of the above dataframe should be:

```
+--------------------+--------------------|------+
|                col1|                col2|Output+
+--------------------+--------------------+------+
|[[563], [242, 178]] |          [563, 178]|     2+
|[[563], [242, 178]] |     [563, 178, 242]|     3+
|[[563], [242, 178]] |     [563, 242, 178]|     3+
|[[563], [242, 178]] |     [242, 178, 563]|     2+
+--------------------+--------------------+------+
```

I'm fairly certain that a UDF is need for this, but I am struggling as to how I would iterate through the sub arrays in col1.

Any help would be appreciated!

Spencer

Answer (score 0):

From **`spark-2`.4** use **`array_intersect`** function with `flatten` function then to get the number of elements in array use `size` function.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show()
#+-------------------+---------------+
#|               col1|           col2|
#+-------------------+---------------+
#|[[563], [242, 178]]|     [563, 178]|
#|[[563], [242, 178]]|[563, 178, 242]|
#+-------------------+---------------+

from pyspark.sql.functions import *


df.withColumn("flattend",flatten(col("col1"))).\
withColumn("output",size(array_intersect(col("col2"),col("flattend")))).\
drop("flattend").\
show()
#+-------------------+---------------+------+
#|               col1|           col2|output|
#+-------------------+---------------+------+
#|[[563], [242, 178]]|     [563, 178]|     2|
#|[[563], [242, 178]]|[563, 178, 242]|     3|
#+-------------------+---------------+------+
```

Comment: this works to find the total number of matches within the two columns, but does not address the issue with order that I outline above.